# Debugging why SPI Master is Reading Arbitary Values

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, spi, device-tree, intel-fpga

I have an SPI bus between a MAX V device and an AM335x processor.
The MAX V device has an SPI setup to repeatedly send a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR defined as "x0100".
This seems to work fine. The output on a scope is repeatedly the same value.

In Linux, I seem to get either shifted data, or some random data. Using spi-tools from here https://github.com/cpb-/spi-tools

When these tools are used, I get the following:

```
# spi-config -d /dev/spidev0.0 -m 1 -s 10000000
# spi-pipe -d /dev/spidev0.0 -b 2 -n 1 < /dev/urandom | hexdump
0000000 0202
0000002
# spi-pipe -d /dev/spidev0.0 -b 2 -n 1 < /dev/urandom | hexdump
0000000 0a0a
0000002
# spi-pipe -d /dev/spidev0.0 -b 2 -n 1 < /dev/urandom | hexdump
0000000 2a2a
0000002
# spi-pipe -d /dev/spidev0.0 -b 2 -n 1 < /dev/urandom | hexdump
0000000 aaaa
0000002
# spi-pipe -d /dev/spidev0.0 -b 2 -n 1 < /dev/urandom | hexdump
0000000 aaaa
0000002
```

You can see how the device is configured there. On the scope, the MISO pin is clearly outputting "00000010 00000000" for **every** 16 clock cycles on SCLK. What is happening here? How can I repeatedly get the correct value from the device?

For clarity, here is the relevant parts of the device tree and the kernel configuration.

**Kernel**

```
CONFIG_SPI=y
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
CONFIG_SPI_GPIO=y
CONFIG_SPI_BITBANG=y
CONFIG_SPI_OMAP24XX=y
CONFIG_SPI_TI_QSPI=y
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
CONFIG_REGMAP_SPI=y
CONFIG_MTD_SPI_NOR=y
CONFIG_SPI_CADENCE_QUADSPI=y
```

**Device Tree**

```
&spi1 {
    /* spi1 bus is connected to the CPLD only on CS0 */
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&spi1_pins>;
    ti,pindir-d0-out-d1-in;
    cpld_spidev: cpld_spidev@0 {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "linux,spidev";
        spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
        reg = <0>;
    };
};
```

Also here is a screengrab of the waveforms produced.
[image]

Really the end goal is an app to report the version stated as the STD_LOGIC_VECTOR, on the MAX V device. So 0100 is intended to be version 1.00.

Comment: `0xAAAA` and  so on are quite suspicious from HW point of view, i.e. they are looks like meander signal, which may point to pin misconfiguration (you got CLK as data).

Comment: I agree. I’m not sure if Linux is doing something odd here. The device tree / pinmux are 100% based on the hardware

Answer (score 0):

Use the uboot_overlay in /boot/uEnv.txt called BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dtbo.

If you need any more info, please ask. Oh! And there is a fellow, Dr. Molloy, that had produced a book a while back.

chp08/spi/ is the location of the file you will need to test the SPI Device.

The command is simply spidev_test

Comment: https://www.oshwa.org/a-resolution-to-redefine-spi-signal-names/ is a thing now. Heads up!

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I am misinterpreting this but using a cape overlay for the beaglebone when this is a custom board is a strange approach, however I will look into modifying my own device tree to be similar.

Comment: Oh...you have a custom board. Okay. No issue. I see you are using the am335x. Okay. Did you try the online, TI.com pinmux tool? It shows the 'overlay' needed or .dts file associated w/ your custom config.